# How to sign an Android APK with multiple keys and certificates

Tags: java, android, apk, keystore, android-keystore

A little background of what we are trying to accomplish.
We are using an Android tablet manufacturer for our product and they are also providing the Android ROM for us so that we no longer need to maintain our own AOSP build.

So now this means that we have a non-rooted tablet in which we need to be able to install system apps, or at least an app with root privileges that can invoke other apps with the same context as the system app that we create and is built into the Android ROM.

This way, later on when we get our tablet we can update this app to do whatever we need and it will run with all privileges and be a system app because it's signed with both our company certificate and key as well as the AOSP platform certificate and key.

Two questions:

1. Do we need to sign the APK with both our own key and certificate and the AOSP platform key and certificate?
2. How do you sign an APK with 2 pairs of key/certificate?

The idea is that the APK will be signed with the platform key so that it has full system app privileges but also be signed with our own key/certificate so that we can update the app when we receive the tablets.

Question 3. Is there a better way to do this? Will signing that APK with the AOSP key/certificate and our own allow us to update this system app in the future? The idea is that we want to be able to upgrade this APK without having to give the tablet manufacturer our certificate/key.

I know that I can create a Java KeyStore that contains one key/certificate and sign an APK in Android Studio using that KeyStore. However, I don't know how to create a Jave KeyStore with multiple key/certificate pairs and sign an APK with all keys/certificates in that Java KeyStore.

Comment: Quick question before a more complete answer: do you intend to update this app via the Play Store? Because they don't support signing with two keys.

Comment: No, this app wont be going into the Play Store.